# Redirecting from old Drupal site to Wordpress site on same domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, drupal, http-status-code-301

I am redesigning an old Drupal site and am switching to Wordpress as the client would like this. The site will be on the same domain but the URL structure will be different.

I am currently working on the site using xampp on my localhost but am not sure what the best way would be to implement the redirects. If I make a .htaccess file and manually input the URL links, would it be fine to delete the old site? and would this keep the ranking on google the same? Also is there a big difference between manually creating the htaccess file vs using a plugin for redirects?

I've read different things online and some of this is old information so am wondering what would be the best way to approach this situation? Any advice or links would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand i came up with the following solution:

You can install WordPress in a sub-directory E.G: /wordpress/ and build the website in that folder while the old website is still online.

When the WordPress website is ready to go online you can redirect the website to the root while still being installed in /wordpress/

To do this you'll have to do 2 simple steps:

1. Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the /WordPress/ directory into the root directory of your site (rename old index.php or index.html to something like indexOLD)
2. Open the copied index.php in a text-editor (the one you just copied) and change the following line:

require( dirname( **FILE** ) . 'wp-blog-header.php' );

============== TO ==============

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

=============

If you don't have hours of down time, and the content stays the same you won't lose your google rankings.

I don't fully understand the redirect part, but i assume that using pretty links (already built in wordpress) will do the job.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will give this a go when the site is ready :)